# Show that $f$ is infinitely differentiable

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ satisfy $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in(0,\infty)$. If $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$, show that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and $f'(x)=\frac{f'(1)}{x}$. Show that $f$ is in fact infinitely differentiable.

What I did:

Let $y=1,$ then $f(x)=f(x)+f(1)$

$\therefore f(1)=0$ is differentiable.

Let $\mid h\mid<x$ and $y=1+\frac{h}{x}$

$f(xy)=f(x(1+\frac{h}{x}))=f(x+h)=f(x)+f(1+\frac{h}{x})=f(x)+f(1)+f'(1)\frac{}{}\frac{h}{x}+\text{o}(\frac{h}{x})$

How do I show that $\frac{\frac{h}{x}}{x-h}\to0$ as $x\to h$? And how do I show that $f$ is infinitely differentibale? I have to prove another function is infinitely differentiable as well so I hope I can apply the same technique there. Thank you guys.

Comment: Did you type $f(x+y)$ instead of $f(xy)$ in  the first line?

Comment: Shoot my bad. Got mixed up with the other quesiton.

Comment: "$f(1)=0$ is differentiable"? $f(1)$ is just a value at one point, not a function. It cannot be differentiable.

Comment: Why do you want to show that $\frac{\frac{h}{x}}{x-h}\to0$ as $x \to h$? When showing differentiability you want to take $h \to 0,$ not $x \to h.$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)} h=\frac {f(x(1+h/x))-f(x)} h =\frac {f(1+h/x)} {h/x} \frac {h/x} h$. Note that $f(1)=f(1)+f(1)$ so $f(1)=0$. Hence we get $f'(x)=\frac  {f'(1)} x$ for all $x$. Since $\frac   1 x$ is infinitely differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ so is $f$.

Comment: How is the first part of your answer able to show that $\frac{\frac{h}{x}}{x-h}\to0$ as $x\to h$? I'm still confused.

Comment: If $t=\frac h x$ then $t \to 0$ as $h \to 0$. Hence$\frac {f(1+t)} t =\frac {f(1+t)-f(1)} {(1+t)-1} \to f'(1)$. @Jess

Answer (score 0):

Fix $x \in (0,\infty)$ and assume that $f'(1)$ is defined. Then, for $h>-x,$ so that $f(1+\frac{h}{x})$ is defined,
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
= \frac{f(x(1+\frac{h}{x}))-f(x)}{h}
= \frac{\left(f(x)+f(1+\frac{h}{x})\right)-f(x)}{h} \\
= \frac{f(1+\frac{h}{x})}{h}
= \frac{f(1+\frac{h}{x})}{\frac{h}{x}} \frac{1}{x}
\to f'(1)  \frac{1}{x}
.
$$
Thus, $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and $f'(x)=\frac{f'(1)}{x}$. And $f$ is infinitely differentiable since $\frac{1}{x}$ is.